# VB.Net - Pick overloaded method with narrowing instead of widening?

Tags: .net, vb.net, overloading

I have a base class, and subclasses of that class. I have a method that takes the base class as an argument, and I've overloaded it with other methods that take a subclass as an argument.

I have a collection that has a function `DoSomething(e as BaseClass)`, which will in turn call DoSomething(e) on each of the items in its collection.

In an ideal world, each child would execute the narrowest version of its own DoSomething. But since the collection's DoSomething is declared as BaseClass, VB's way of picking which overload eliminates anything that would require narrowing. So it always calls each child's `DoSomething(e as BaseClass)` and never, say, `DoSomething(e as SubClassFromBaseClass)`.

Is there a way of doing this automagically in .Net?  Right now my only idea is to have if/else with type checking.

```
If e Is SubClass1 Then
  DoSomething(CType(e, SubClass1))
ElseIf e Is Subclass2 Then
  DoSomething(Ctype(e, SubClass2))
...
End If
```

It would be nice to be able to just add a new overload to of DoSomething to one of the child classes without having to add the ElseIf... for each type. (or to use reflection...)

Comment: No, that's not happening. If you were to set `Option Strict Off` and start with an `Object` reference then it might work as you want, although I'm still not sure it would. That would be a filthy hack anyway.

Comment: The only way that I can think to get what you want is to have `DoSomething` be a member of the contained item, then you can use overrides to call the correct version for the runtime type of the item.